# Web server running python.

Tags: apache, iis, web, server, webserver

I want to create a web server that I can accesses over the internet (not just locally) and can run and execute python scripts. These scripts will be doing some querying on .db files and returning processed query results. I want to be able to run POST and GET methods on my web server. How should I go about doing this? This is for a school project. From my research, I would need a dedicated computer to be my web server and I don't have those resources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Flask.  It will work as a simple web server that let's you run POST and GET against it as well as serving pages.  Since it is a Python application, running Python scripts are just part of the code.

In addition to it accomplishing what you want, you could run this on just about any computer you could load Python on (Windows, Linux, Mac, Raspberry PI) thus eliminating the requirement for a dedicated computer.

http://flask.pocoo.org